# imperative to functional: n-body collision

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm a beginner in functional programming but I'm famaliar with imperative programming. I'm having trouble translating a piece of cpp code involving updatating two objects at the same time (context is n-body simulation).

It's roughly like this in c++:

```cpp
for (Particle &i: particles) {
  for (Particle &j: particles) {
     collide(i, j) // function that mutates particles i and j
  }
}
```

I'm translating this to Ocaml, with immutable objects and immutable Lists. The difficult part is that I need to replace two objects at the same time. So far I have this:

```ml
List.map (fun i ->
  List.map (fun j ->
    let (new_i, new_j) = collide(i, j) in // function that returns new particles i, j
    // how do i update particles with new i, j?
  ) particles
) particles
```

How do I replace both objects in the List at the same time?

Comment: What does the C++ look like exactly? Does `collide` really mutate both particles? If yes, do you really want to collide all pairs twice (once as `collide(a, b)` and once as `collide(b, a)`)? Also do you want to collide a particle with itself?

Answer (score 2):

The functional equivalent of the imperative code is just as simple as,

```
let nbody f xs =
  List.map (fun x -> List.fold_left f x xs) xs
```

It is a bit more generic, as a I abstracted the collide function and made it a parameter. The function `f` takes two bodies and returns the state of the first body as affected by the second body. For example, we can implement the following symbolic `collide` function,

```
let symbolic x y = "f(" ^ x ^ "," ^ y ^ ")"
```

so that we can see the result and associativity of the the collide function application,

```
# nbody symbolic [
    "x"; "y"; "z"
];;
- : string list =
["f(f(f(x,x),y),z)"; "f(f(f(y,x),y),z)"; "f(f(f(z,x),y),z)"]
```

So, the first element of the output list is the result of collision of `x` with `x` itself, then with `y`, then with `z`. The second element is the result of collision of `y` with `x`, and `y`, and `z`. And so on.

Obviously the body shall not collide with itself, but this could be easily fixed by either modifying the `collide` function or by filtering the input list to `List.fold` and removing the currently being computed element. This is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

`List.map` returns a new list. The function you supply to `List.map` may transform the elements from one *type* to another or just apply some operation on the same *type*.

For example, let's assume you start with a list of integer *tuples*

```ml
let int_tuples = [(1, 3); (4, 3); (8, 2)];;
```

and let's assume that your update function takes an integer tuple and doubles the integers:

```ml
let update (i, j) = (i * 2, j * 2) (* update maybe your collide function *)
```

If you now do:

```ml
let new_int_tuples = List.map update int_tuples
```

You'll get

```ml
(* [(2, 6); (8, 6); (16, 4)] *)
```

Hope this helps